# Entity framework creating additional ID field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I am developing an application where I am using Entity framework. I have an abstract class called BaseEntity which is inherited by all other classes; it contains properties which are common to all other classes - Id(PK), CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, CreatedBy and ModifiedBy.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedDate
        {
            get ; set ;
        }

        public DateTime? ModifiedDate
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] Version { get; set; }

    }
```

I have a class called City which inherits the above class

```
public class City : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

The problem I am having now is Entity framework is rightfully inserting the PK value in the column Id but its creating an extra column City_Id which is null. Since I am using the Id column from the base class as the PK I don't need the City_Id column. How can I get rid of it? I know it's the convention of Entity Framework to use ID or Type_Id as the PK.

Fluent API configuration

```
public class CityConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<City>
{
    public CityConfig()
    {
        Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);

        Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);

        Property(x => x.ModifiedBy).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);

    }
}
```

And my context is as shown below

```
public virtual DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //Other lines removed for brevity

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CityConfig());

    }
```

Comment: the code above will not create City_Id column show me your DbContext do you have used Fluent API extra do configure the code? your example will just create one id in the table because the base class is abstract

Comment: Yes I have used Fluent API to do extra configuration

Comment: write your db configurations plz.#

Comment: @BassamAlugili I have done so, kindly check again.

Comment: Maybe in your CityConfig you should specify property Id for example: `HasKey(x => x.Id)`

Comment: I tried that but still same results.